# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = field value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect

In my database table i have a field with usernames.

I want the users that are NOT in that field to be redirected to my default websites.
I dont want the users to be able to copy past the URL for another of my aspx sites only if they are users from my field then its ok

Im looking into User.Identity.IsAuthenticated but how would i combine that with my database field?

```
 If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = "fieldvalue" then 
      site1.aspx
 Else
      Server.transfer("default.aspx)
 End If
```

Should i mabye say something like.

```
If sqlexecute.hasrows then 
   Site1.aspx
Else 
server.transfere("default.aspx")
End IF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is a boolean property and can contain only `true/false` value. You can just check for truthfulness of `IsAuthenticated` property and then do the redirection like

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  //redirect to site1.aspx 
}
else 
{
  Server.transfer("default.aspx");
}
```

**EDIT:**

You are trying to reinvent the wheel. What you are trying is already built into ASP.NET and known as [`Forms Authentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

It's very well explained in MSDN. See below MSDN links

[Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

[How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, is the only way to stop users from copy the URL to use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated? Or is it rather the server.transfer line that does it?...

Comment: what you mean by `copy the URL`? coping from browser address bar? above answer has nothing to do with that. What you are exactly trying to do here?

Comment: Yes copy the URL browser adress. The users should not be able to copy and past to site1.aspx if they are not listed in my field.

Comment: I use User.Identity.Name to see what users is on my page and then i want to "key" that user with my field value(username) in the database and only let the users from my field be able to skip default.aspx page if they want to

Comment: @Nils, If I have understood correct then you are looking for `Forms Authentication`. See edited answer.

Comment: @Nils, consider accepting the answer if you have found it's helpful.

Comment: ofcource but i don´t know where to "accept" the help?.

Comment: @Nils, there is a check button under voting up/down button.